# Сортировка в нужном порядке

Tags: mysql

Требуется создать свой порядок сортировки вида: `1,2,3,null,null,null,null`. Пробовал создать дополнительное поле, и пронумеровать нужное. 

 Но при запросе `ORDER BY price_order ASC` выдает `null,null,null,null,1,2,3` а если `ORDER BY price_order DESC 3,2,1,null,null,null,null`. Помогите решить...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ORDER BY price_order IS NULL, price_order ASC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd35dc/9